# 2 Radio buttons on same line in jquery mobile and dispaly phone number field

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying form design in jquery mobile. In my form i want to show two radio buttons on same line. I try to use `display: inline` but not working. 
Second one I searched in jquery mobile documentation for showing phone number field with three text field(separating the phone number) but i didn't get any design like this. Any suggestions to how to do this in jquery mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution you are looking for maybe involving **Content Grids**.

Documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html

I have mocked up some HTML for doing this for radio buttons and text boxes, but your situation may be a little different.

Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/XxB6Y/

Also, check out this documentation page for text inputs for (telephone) numbers:

> In jQuery Mobile, you can use existing and new HTML5 input types such
>   as password, email, tel, number, and more.

From here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/textinputs/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to how to get phone number with three text field like xxx-xxx-xxxx.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XxB6Y/1/

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons need very aggressive display:inline !important; ... In addition you have to fiddle with the heights of those text boxes to make them align nicely.   Here is two versions for you, one with normal buttons and the other with the minis.

http://jsfiddle.net/den232/bVF3B/

Good Luck!

```
    .floatleft {
    float:left;
 }
.floatright {
    float:right;
 }
.forceinline{  /* Prevent fieldcontain from doing a BLOCK thing */
    display:inline !important;
}
.textwidth {  /* limit width of input fields */
    width:80px;
}
.closespacing { /* controls spacing between elements */
    margin:0px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
.bigselect {   /* centers select with big buttons */
    padding: 0px;
    margin:2px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
.biginputheight {   /* matches text input height to big buttons */
    padding-top:10px !important;
    padding-bottom:12px !important;
}
.miniinputheight { /* matches text input height to minibuttons */
    padding-top:5px !important;
    padding-bottom:5px !important;
}
<div data-role="page" class="type-home">
```

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">first LI line</li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">

    <div class='floatleft closespacing'>
        Big Buttons<br>More Text
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class= 'forceinline'>
      <div class='floatleft closespacing'>    
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="aa"  />
          <label for="radio-view-a">A1</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="bb"  />
          <label for="radio-view-b">B1</label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="#1" class='biginputheight'></input>
    </div>  

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="#2" class='biginputheight'></input>
    </div>  

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="#3" class='biginputheight'></input>
    </div>  

    <div  class='floatright textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="right" class='biginputheight'></input>
    </div>  

  </li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">

    <div class='floatleft closespacing'>    
        Small Buttons
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class= 'forceinline'>
      <div class='floatleft closespacing'>    
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini='true'>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-a" value="aa"  />
          <label for="radio-view-a">AA</label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radio-view-b" value="bb"  />
          <label for="radio-view-b">BB</label>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="s1" class='miniinputheight'></input>
    </div>  

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="s2" class='miniinputheight'></input>
    </div>  

    <div  class='floatleft textwidth'>
      <input type="text" placeholder="s2" class='miniinputheight'></input>
    </div>  


    <div class='floatright closespacing'>
      <div  class='floatright closespacing'>    
        e3 Text<br>on right
      </div>
      <div  class='floatright textwidth'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="e3" class='miniinputheight'></input>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </li>
  <li  data-role="fieldcontain">last LI line</li>

</ul><!-- /listview -->
```